# Get the last occurrence of string within another string

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript function to get the last occurrence of a substring in a String

Like:

```
var url = "/home/doc/some-user-project/project";
```

I would like a function that returns `true` if the String contains **project** at his end.

I know `str.indexOf()` or `str.lastIndexOf()` but is there another function that do the job or should I do it?

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
var check = "project",
    url = "/home/doc/some-user-project/project";

if (url.substr(-check.length) == check){
  // it ends with it..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
var url = "/home/doc/some-user-project/project";
url.match(/project$/);
</script>
```

The response is a array with project, if the responde is 'null' because it is not found